# Configure VS to generate XBF but not code behind for UWP

Tags: uwp-xaml, c++-winrt

I just discovered a method to quickly develop UWP application using C++/WinRT by using [Application::LoadComponent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.application.loadcomponent) thank to Kenny Kerr's old samples and auto-generated code:

1. Add the xaml as content (to copy to the app deployment) in the VS project file `.vcxproj`

```
    <ItemGroup>
        <None Include="MainPage.xaml">
            <DeploymentContent>true</DeploymentContent>
        </None>
    </ItemGroup>
```

2. Load the XAML in code, for example, in `App::OnLaunch`

```
    // Load the page layout from XAML
    Page page;
    Application::LoadComponent(page, Uri {L"ms-appx:///MainPage.xaml"});

    // Obtain components such as
    button = page.FindName(L"MyButton").as<Button>();
    // and bind their event handlers as necessary
```

This way, every time I change the XAML source, there is no need to recompile (fairly long wait) due to updated auto-generated headers (those `XamlBindingInfo.g.h`, `MainPage.g.h`, ...): VS just need to copy the updated XAML to the deployment. This works fairly well for me since I don't need much data/event binding.

My question is: I want to change the configuration in step 1 so that Visual Studio generates the compiled XAML binary format `*.xbf` but NOT the code behind for efficiency. How do I change the VS project config file?

Comment: Edit vcxproj file is already a change of project config file in my point of view. So maybe you mean you want to edit the build option?

Comment: @BarryWang-MSFT Maybe. I want to somehow add a build step to produce the `xbf` file from `xaml` file and copy to deployment, but no auto-generated code behind.

Comment: I guess you may need to have some post build events like this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-specify-build-events-csharp?view=vs-2019 This is the only thing that in my mind which might be helpful. However I don't have an idea about how we can do this.